# float vector and pointer returns different values even though they have same adress

Tags: c++

I have a class which returns `vector<vector<float>>` with its `getTemplates()` function. My code is as follows for this case:

```
cout << "Get [0][0] " << s.getTemplates()[0][0] << endl;
cout << "vec addr " <<  &(s.getTemplates()[0][0]) << endl;

float *embFloat = s.getTemplates()[0].data();
cout << "embFloat: " << embFloat << endl;
cout << "*embFloat " << *embFloat << endl;
cout << "embFloat[0] " << embFloat[0] << endl;
```

and the output is as follows:

```
Get [0][0] 0.00191223
vec addr 0x555557973280
embFloat: 0x555557973280
*embFloat -8.71571e+33
embFloat[0] -8.71571e+33
```

I expect `embFloat[0]` and `s.getTemplates()[0][0]` to return exactly same value. What am I missing here?

Comment: If `getTemplates` really returns a `vector<vector<float>>` (by value) `s.getTemplates()[0].data();` will yield a pointer that's immediately dangling at the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.getTemplates()` returns a temporary which (in this particular instance) goes out of scope at the end of the statement that contains it.

`float *embFloat` is therefore a dangling pointer - i.e. it's pointing to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: ... And next time, [mre] please.